# Unity3D: void OnEnable() is called Unpredictably in Editor Mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I implemented OnEnable() and it is always called in Play mode as expected. But in Editor Mode some components call OnEnable() and other don't

I need OnEnable() or other method to be called in Editor Mode to setup component to be able to prototype it.

If I extend class from UnityEngine.UI.Image then OnEnable() is called in Editor Mode. If I extend class from MonoBehavior then it does not call OnEnable() in Editor Mode but still being called in Play Mode.

Is there any clarification why it is called or not called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`MonoBehaviour.OnEnable()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html) is called when the script component is actived. `UnityEngine.UI.Image` inherits from `MonoBehaviour`, so there should be no difference. You may need to have a look at [Execution Order of Event Functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

If you want your `MonoBehaviour` called by the editor, you should add a [`ExecuteInEditMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) attribute to your class.

Comment: Thanks. May be `UI.Image` has that flag

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks. May be UI.Image has that flag

Exactly !

[image: UI.Image inherits from MaskableGraphic.]
`UI.Image` inherits from `MaskableGraphic`.

[image: MaskableGraphic inherits from Graphic.]
`MaskableGraphic` inherits from `Graphic`.

[image: Graphic has the ExecuteInEditMode]
And `Graphic` has the `ExecuteInEditMode` flag !

---

ps1: @zwcloud is right about [ExecuteInEditMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) attribute!, this answer is my two cents.

ps2; you can always `Go the declaration` of the class and check the code, it could be very fun !
 [image: Go to declaration]